# How to deal with limits with fancy grids

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am discovering the beautiful world of home-made grids with Matplotlib. Here is my code that gives the following output as figure:

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from mpl_toolkits.axisartist             import (SubplotHost, GridHelperCurveLinear)
from mpl_toolkits.axisartist.grid_finder import (FixedLocator)

fig = plt.figure()

def tr(x, y): return np.log10(x) + np.log10(y), np.log10(y) - np.log10(x)
def inv_tr(x, y): return 10 ** ((x - y) / 2), 10 ** ((x + y) / 2)

grid_helper = GridHelperCurveLinear((tr, inv_tr))

axis = SubplotHost(fig, 111, grid_helper=grid_helper)
fig.add_axes(axis)

axis.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

What I want is nothing more than choosing the limits of my axis. Of course I can use `set_xlim()` and `set_ylim()`, which will work, but before the transformation. Meaning that in this figure, the limits are supposed to be (0,1). How can I define precisely the bounds, for example if I want (0.1, 15) horizontally and (2,20) vertically?